# Android custom view: Set canvas size to wrap bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that has `Canvas` in it. I'm using this canvas to show a bitmap on it and then I can draw over the bitmap on touch. When I load the bitmap it is a lot bigger then the view size and I can't see the whole bitmap (it's picture taken with camera). I tried to create scaled bitmap and then draw it on the canvas, but in that case the bitmap is smaller and the canvas is taking the whole layout space available. I'm adding this view programmatically, not int the xml layout. I have set this to the view but not working:

```
fdvImage = new ImageEditingView(this, b);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
fdvImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

and this is my view constructor:

```
public ImageEditingView(Context c, Bitmap b) {
    super(c);
    this.setMinimumHeight(0);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2, true);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

and in the `onDraw` I have this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
}
```

**So, my question is:** Why is the canvas taking all the layout space even if the bitmap is smaller then it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to draw bitmap

```
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(yourBitmap, 1, 1,vertices, 0, null, 0,
                                        paint);
```

Make vertices according  to your view

**[EDIT]**

```
    float[] vertices = new float[8];
 vertices[0]=0; vertices[1]=0; vertices[2]=100; vertices[3]=0;
 vertices[4]=0;vertices[5]=200; vertices[6]=100; vertices[7]=200;
```

change the 100 to your width and 200 to height

Comment: what should I put instead of vertices? How to make these vertices?

Comment: this is ok, but I have one problem. The view is created in the onCreate and I don't have the width and height that the image should have. The view is added inside relative layout, but I can't get the width and height because this is called in onCreate

Comment: use onWindowFocusChanged to get height and width

Comment: This is it. I get the dimensions of the layout in `onWindowFocusChanged` and draw the bitmap on the canvas there. I don't need the `canvas.drawBitmapMesh`. Since I have the dimensions I create the scaled bitmap and then draw it.